# Cart Summary In Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, shopping-cart, helper

I develop an ecommerce application. I using C#, MVC and Entity Framework and Bootstrap.
I've saved cart item in my database. My question is :
I want to show cart's summary in my layout's top. But what's your suggestion for this operation.
Should i use a partial view for the cart's summary or another way?

And in other hand how can i read my cart's data from database every request. i cannot it in from controllers of course. because i want to show cart's summary top of the screen at every page. should i read it from application start or ? Any suggest me pls for this operations.

```
//_Layout.cshtml
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">E-Commerce</a>
            </div>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Arama">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">

                /* I want to see shopping cart summary in this section*/ 

                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                <span id="cartTotal">

                </span>
                (<span id="cartItemCount"></span>)
            </p>
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">Log In</p>
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">Register</p>

        </nav>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you shoud use `Html.Action` to invoke Action taht returns PartialView.

Comment: Design-wise:
1. Showing whatever in whatever view - write some jQuery to render display and only transfer raw data - this will ensure speed.
2. Storing the cart is best done in the session unless you want specifically that as a feature where user'd login and get the same persistent cart. then read it on login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use of this solution

in Controller

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult CartSummary()
    {   
        ViewData["CartCount"] = 3; // count Qty in your cart
        return PartialView("CartSummary");
    }
```

right click and Add view and select PartialView then in PartialView

```
@ViewData["CartCount"]
```

in layout, where you want to show cart's qty

```
@{Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "controllerName");}
```